# C++ Primer (5th edition); Ch 19 - Algorithms: std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, algorithm, language-lawyer, lower-bound

This is from *C++ Primer (5<sup>th</sup> edition)*; Ch 19. "Appendix: algorithms":

> ```
> lower_bound(beg, end, val)
> lower_bound(beg, end, val, comp)
> ```
>
> Returns an iterator denoting the first element such that `val` is not less than that element, or `end` if no such element exists.
>
> ```
> upper_bound(beg, end, val)
> upper_bound(beg, end, val, comp)
> ```
>
> Returns an iterator denoting the first element

- But I think `lower_bound` returns an iterator denoting the first element in the input sequence that is not less than `val` (greater than or equal to val) not the contrary ("...first element such that `val` is not less than that element"). Is it a mistake in the book?

Comment: Seems like it.  Have you tried submitting an errata of emailing the authors?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound says exactly your words, so probably a typo, yes

Comment: @selbie: How can I?

Comment: contact the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it a mistake in the book?*

If you trust [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), then: Yes, it is a mistake:

> #### `std::lower_bound`
>
> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range `[first, last)` that is *not less* than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last if no such element is found.

Or, if you *don't* trust that website, [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) has:

> ##### 28.7.3.1 `lower_bound`       `[lower.bound]`
>
> …
> <sup>2</sup>     *Returns:* The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first, i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*j < value` or `comp(*j, value) != false`.

In [this (later) online Draft Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/lower.bound), it's **§25.8.4.2**.